# Pointer declaration syntax using & and Intptr. Are both identical?

Tags: c#

Case 1:

```
int i;
int* pi = &i;
```

Case 2:

```
int i;
IntPtr pi = &i;
```

Are both cases identical?

My purpose is that:-

1. I am copying a value to string variable.
2. Converting string to bytes array
3. using Marshal.Alloc(sizeofBytesArray) to get IntPtr ptrToArray
4. marshal.copy(array,0,ptrToArray,sizeofBytesArray)
5. Sending this ptrToArray to a vb6 application by using a structure and passing structure via SendMessage win32 api.

On VB6 app:-

1. I am picking up the value from the structure that gives me the address of the array.
2. using CopyMemory to copy the bytesarray data into a string..

More Code:

```
string aString = text;
            byte[] theBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aString);

            // Marshal the managed struct to a native block of memory.
            int myStructSize = theBytes.Length;
            IntPtr pMyStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myStructSize); //int* or IntPtr is good?
            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(theBytes, 0, pMyStruct, myStructSize);
...............
```

Comment: don't use pointers in C#, unless you're dealing with lower level stuff such as C++ interop, P/Invoke and the like.

Comment: @HighCore: Well we don't know what the OP is actually trying to do. This might be fine.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thats why I removed my comment.

Comment: I am using copymemory so I do require pointer use...

Comment: Either one is fine. `IntPtr` exists purely for that purpose when a language cannot declare a pointer.

Comment: Looks like you might need `char*` or `byte*` a lot more than `int*`. Either way, post some concrete code. The Marshaller will usually let you use `string` or `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @NachiketKamat You can request for more info or you can accept my answer, as it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the msdn page:-

> The IntPtr type can be used by languages that support pointers, and as a common means of referring to data between languages that do and do not support pointers.
>
> IntPtr objects can also be used to hold handles. For example, instances of IntPtr are used extensively in the System.IO.FileStream class to hold file handles.

**Are both cases indentical?**

No, they are not identical,
The difference is in the underlying implementation of `IntPtr`

forex

```
  int i = 10 ; 
  int *pi = i ; 
  int c = *pi ; // would work
```

but to do the same thing , you have to cast `IntPtr` to int*

```
 int i =10 ; 
 IntPtr pi = &i ; 
 int *tempPtr = (int*)pi ; 
 int c = *tempPtr ;
```

The internal representation of `IntPtr` is like  `void*` but it is  exposed like an integer. You can use it whenever you need to store an unmanaged pointer and don't want to use unsafe code.

It has  two limitations:

1. It cannot be dereferenced directly (you have to cast it as a true pointer).
2. It doesn't know the type of the data that it points to. (because of `void*`)